# Can we restrict a mongodb user from exporting a database, while having just read/view permission?

Tags: mongodb

I tried to search mongodb docs however I could not find anything relevant

I would like to know if its possible or not. If so how?

I have a created a user with just read permission, this restricts user to update, insert/import and delete any documents however exporting still works.

If there is a solution, please guide me with steps to do so.

Comment: If a user can read a database, he can read the entire database into a copy.  Sure, it's more difficult than exporting a database, but it can still be done.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc true, however it take very very long time to do so and very difficult you have track how many records you have copied. It's too exhausting to do it.